# How to set image for Tabbar item in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I have a tabbar application created using Interface builder. When I try to set Custom

Image for tabBar Item does not show up.

Can Anyone Please help me in this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can anything to Tabbar Controller as a subview like [tabBarController.tabBar addSubview:imgTab];

Answer (score 0):

you could programmatically set the image with the following line of code

```
UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:anImage tag:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alterative:

You can drag and drop a image into your resourses folder and then in interface builder goto the TabBar items attributes change the image to the image to dropped into the resourses folder.

Answer (score 0):

see this link you will see the demo for making tab bar application in this where you select the tab for give name at that options you can see IMAGE option so you can specify your tab image their..
[Here](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller-tutorial/)